Zener Diode as DC Voltage Regulator
I am currently working on PCB and would like to add an LED Power indicator. Unfortunately the input power can either be 12V or 24V DC, so choosing the exact resistance is not possible.
However, I was wondering if using Zener Diode(BZT52C5V1S-7-F) would be an ideal fit for this scenario.
Below is a picture of the schematic and a link to the datasheet of the diode I will be using. Please note that the LED will be green which approximately has a forward voltage of 2.0-2.1V.
Is there any concerns with the schematic or properties of this specific models zener diode?
Any advice would help.
https://mm.digikey.com/Volume0/opasdata/d220001/medias/docus/804/BZT52C2V0S-BZT52C39S.pdf


Your requirement for an "indicator" seems overly-exact, if this is meant for eye-viewing. In the interest of reducing parts count may I suggest no zener, and one series resistor designed for 24V. For 12V supply, slightly less than half-intensity will be a hardly-noticeable difference. If viewing must be in bright sunlight AND in darkness, your zener idea is perhaps better.

@glen_geek yeah (this is for eye-viewing). This schematic is a component of a power distribution board and I was tasked with designing it. I don't know to much about the battery being used but I was just looking to see if this idea was even feasible.

If you want to put 20 mA through the LED (which seems excessive), you're going to have to reduce the value of R1 to about \$\frac{12 V - 5 V}{20 mA} = 330 \Omega\$.
This will put about \$\frac{24 V - 5 V}{330 \Omega} - 20 mA = 37 mA\$ through the zener when connected to the higher voltage, requiring it to dissipate about 190 mW.
I would recommend reducing the LED current to no more than 5 mA. Keep R1 at 1000 Ω, but increase R2 to 620 Ω.

Thanks, I was struggling a bit with the math as I wanted to be within the power dissipation constraints. I will probably do some physical testing to determine the appropriate resistance based on the brightness.
